# How to Change the / to the \/ in php?

Tags: php

I want to replace all forward slashes `/` in my URL  with `\/`.

For example, this URL

```
 http://media3.giphy.com/media/8etoa2PC4Mgx2/200w.mp4
```

should be changed to

```
http:\/\/media3.giphy.com\/media\/8etoa2PC4Mgx2\/200w.mp4
```

I have tried to do this with this code:

```
<?php
    $filename="http://media3.giphy.com/media/8etoa2PC4Mgx2/200w.mp4"
    $filename=str_replace("\//","\/","$filename");
    echo $filename:
?>
```

but it is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: `str_replace("\/","\\/","$filename");` might do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filename = str_replace( "/", "\/", $filename );
```

Do not wrap`$filename` in quotes, because it's a variable. If you remove the quotes in third `str_replace` parameter, it should works.

**Edit:** You need to escape backslash ( `\` ) only, because it has special meaning in [PHP](http://php.net/language.types.string).

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (). To
>   specify a literal backslash, double it (\). All other instances of
>   backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: this means that the
>   other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be
>   output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

at end not `:`(colon) it is `;`(semicolon) and not quotes `"` for `$filename`

```
<?php
$filename="http://media3.giphy.com/media/8etoa2PC4Mgx2/200w.mp4";
$filename=str_replace("/","\/",$filename);
echo $filename;
?>
```